# How to add new rows at top programmatically in WPF grid (.NET5)

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, .net-5

I am using WPF with .NET5 to develop a Windows app where I am using Grid to display some content, and I need to programmatically add a new row at the top of the grid.

One method I considered is modifying row number of each existing row but it's a tedious task. I am using grid to display the content as grid expands dynamically with the expansion of the main window whereas as far as I know, other containers do not show this behavior.

Another method I considered is inserting a row using gridName.Childern.Insert() but it inserts and overlaps the existing row.

I need a solution to either dynamically add a new row at top of the grid without overlapping or to make other containers such as Stack Panel and Dock Panel expand while maximizing the main window.

Is there any other efficient way of achieving this functionality?

Comment: You have to set the `Grid.Row` property on all child elements if you want to "insert" a row at the top. You would also have to update the Grid's `RowDefinitions`. Consider using a more appropriate Panel, e.g. a StackPanel.

Comment: Yeah! Considered that as well but Stack Panel is not responsive like grid. Stack Panel does not expand in expanding the window.

Comment: Then update RowDefinitions and all Grid.Row settings, as already said. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very annoying problem.

You have to change all Grid.Row, Grid.Column

But You can choice other thins

if you need only one orientation, you can use StackPanel

if not, You should use WrapPanel

Comment: Yeah! Considered both as well but Stack Panel and Wrap Panel are not responsive like grid. Both does not expand on expanding window.

Comment: @ArunChaulagain And if each row in the StackPanel is a single-row Grid, would that help?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thanks you so much.  I followed similar apporach. I used stack pack and inside stack panel i used Grid. And Finally By making HorizointalAlignment="Stretch" it worked out.